# Count the number of words in .doc, .docx, .rtf or .pdf file in php

Tags: php

I have an application in PHP which accepts .doc, .docx, .pdf and .rtf files from the user. The application then counts the number of words in the uploaded document to calculate the price.

I have been searching for this issue. All i got that this could easily be done with COM class, but that only works on windows servers and not Linux. My application runs on Linux server.

Could anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Count the number of spaces in the file?

Comment: @Chris that wouldn't work because the files aren't plain text

Comment: @Chris that will not work.  These files are not plain text files.  A lot of 0x20 characters will be part of formatting or binary representation of the file.  You have to actually extract the text first, then count words in the text.  Further, number of spaces isn't right, as it doesn't take into account paragraphs, quotes, etc.

Comment: This is quite a non-trivial problem. Our company once requisitioned a quick prototype for exactly the same thing, and it turned out to break under all sorts of different conditions with different versions of .doc files from different Office versions. What you need is a really robust parser library for each format plus a really robust counting algorithm. The most robust for .doc is obviously Office itself. Go research. Good luck.

Comment: *(Never thought I'd use the word "robust" and "Office" in the same sentence.)*

Comment: @AleksG i can't get the whole content of the word file as that will give me loads of gibberish!

Comment: @JitendraPurohit Word 97 is a binary format and `docx` is a compressed xml "folder" that I think can actually contain Word 97 data too, so you need something like apache poi, which is java though. (and docx is still experimental for poi. and since even the "stable" part of poi is pretty "beta" in terms of features, this is not a good sign for you. Text extraction might work though)

Comment: @dualed can we do that in PHP?

Comment: Not directly I think, but you can write a java program and call it from PHP

Comment: I may not be helpeful here. We got the same requirement before. Other than spending time and time on finding the solution, we turned to calculate the filesize for charges. For example 4M for 1$.

Comment: @AaronJiang That would be the extreme solution!

Comment: @AaronJiang I hope they don't put huge images inside...

Comment: The info you need is not stored anywhere in the file.  Whatever you do, you will need to actually read the file (either in your code or using some third party library), which means you will need to load the whole file anyway. From what you described, I don't think you'll be able to achieve it.  Either change requirements or change the deployment platform and use windows.

Comment: If you can read the file (doc, docx, or other) why don't using '[str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)' method? You can create a function reading the file, and count the number of the word on this...

Comment: @DocRoms the problem is that PHP cannot read the file until it is running on Windows!

Comment: There are many PHP libraries which can or purport to be able to read various .DOC or PDF formats! Google for them. Test them for your use case! Decide if they work well enough.

Comment: @deceze there are not many PHP libraries at all that can actually read binary ms office formats. Actually none.

Comment: I don't see why this question was closed.  And specifically the reason given doesn't fit. My answer itself proves that it can be answered

Answer (score 1):

### Apache POI

Apache POI can extract from Microsoft formats. Text extraction is fairly straight forward, so it should be fine, even though docx is considered experimental as far as I know

Creating a simple command-line program that either returns word count directly or returns the text contents of your file should be fairly straight forward. I have used POI before to index Microsoft documents and it worked quite well.

### LibreOffice / OpenOffice

- `soffice --headless --convert-to txt:text <file>`
- Can also handle `.odt`, `.rtf`, etc... (not PDF though)
- May not be the fastest solution though

There are also some libraries that do basically the same, while providing a common interface, like

- [Docvert](http://static.holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html)

### Negatives

As it was mentioned in the comments that there are "*many*" such libraries out there, I did some research, which was not very successful; I found the following libraries but none seem to actually have the required features

- [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/): Can only *write* docx
- [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/): Is also only meant for generating, but can extract from existing docx, however not from binary doc format. The Pro version has a converter, but it requires Java so I would bet it uses Apache POI in the background.

---

For PDF you would have to get another solution however. But there are really **tons** of PHP PDF libraries out there and most of them are at least decent as PDF is a well-defined format if nothing else.